# I'm trying to use javascript to open a popup window. It works in Chrome but not in IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm trying to use javascript to open a popup window.  It works in chrome but not in IE or Firefox.

Here is my code for the head section:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=400,width=400,left=550,top=200,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
</head>
```

And my code in the body section:

```
 <body>
    <a href="javascript:newPopup('buy-now/ambush-jacket.html');" target="_new"><img     src="images/banner/buy.gif"></a>
    </body
```

>

And here is a link to the page:
http://riverswest.com/riverswest-site/ambush-jacket.html

The BUY NOW image what you want to click on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your target="". You don't need it if you're going to be using javascript popup code.

This works fine:

```
<a href="javascript:newPopup('buy-now/ambush-jacket.html');"><img src="images/banner/buy.gif"></a>
```

Comment: argh!  I forget popups don't need targets. Thanks So Much!