# How to open a link in a new window?

Tags: javascript, html, window, href

I'm trying to make a window popup with my link using HTML & JS.

So far I've managed to get this
`<a href="myLink" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">myText</a>`, but this just makes the link open in a new tab.

Comment: *How to open a link in a new window* => this is exactly what you already doing.

Comment: What is your actual question please ?

Comment: check the link : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005077/im-trying-to-use-javascript-to-open-a-popup-window-it-works-in-chrome-but-not
Maybe this helps

Comment: Its in the title "How to open a link in a new window?", what I'm doing is opening it in a new tab. I want it to popout as a new chrome window (for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to open a link in a new window.

```
<a href="myLink" 
 target="popup" 
 onclick="window.open('myLink','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;">
   Open Link in Popup
</a>
```

Always remember the sometimes that user configures their browsers to block all new tabs and windows (at least this is what I do), to avoid annoying advertisements and click baits links.

Answer (score 1):

Any method which opens a new browser context without specifying the dimensions will use either a tab or a window according to the user's preferences.

In general, it isn't a good idea to try to bypass that preference. If a user decides they want a tab in a new window, they can always tear it off into one.

That said, if you specify dimensions, it will trigger a new window if the browser supports that at all (most mobile devices, for example, don't support windows at all).

```js
addEventListener("click", event => {
    const target = event.target;
    if (!target.classList.contains("force-window")) {
        return;
    }
    const url = target.href;
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight;
    const features = `width=${width},height=${height}`;
    window.open(url, "_blank", features);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<a href="myLink" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" class="force-window">myText</a>
```

Unfortunately, this will produce a window missing most of the expected features. See [the `window.open` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to add them back, but note that (in Chrome *at least*) adding the menubar back will cause the height and width to be ignored and put things back in a new tab.

Author controlled new windows are a pain and are almost always best avoided. I wouldn't touch them unless I needed to do something like pop out some content (like a chat or music player) in a small window that could remain on screen while the user navigated the site … and even then I'd generally lean towards writing a SPA instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to open a popup with a given url, you have to use the `window.open()` function.

The `windows.open()` accepts a few parameters called Window features, which you can find here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features, to define the popup. When you pass it a *width* and a *height* it will open in a popup.

```
<a id="url" href="https://www.google.com">myText</a>

<script>
  document.getElementById("url").addEventListener('click', evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let elem = document.getElementById("url");
    let url = elem.getAttribute("href");
    window.open(url, "popup", "width=700,height=700");
  });
</script>
```